# "Find My" app continually tracking iPhone and MacBook location since latest software update

Tags: iphone, mac, privacy, find-my

Since updating my iPhone to iOS 15.0 and MacBook to macOS 11.6 last week, both devices are continually actuating location services whenever BlueTooth is enabled.

I see this as a solid white compass arrow in the menubars of both devices. I see it is due to the “Find My” app in iPhone Settings / Privacy / Location Services / System Services, where Find My iPhone has the only purple arrow to indicate recent tracking, and in macOS System Preferences / Security & Privacy / Privacy / Location Services, where Find My has the only grey arrow to indicate tracking within the last 24 hours.

I previously only saw the compass arrow when using an app or service that I expected to check my location. I changed nothing and gave no permission to change anything regarding location tracking during the OS updates last week. I notice that iOS Find My App has an “Item Safety Alerts” that was enabled, which I don’t recall having noticed before, but disabling it doesn’t stop the tracking.

I called Apple, where one person told me the compass arrow was always there and suggested I never noticed, and another told me the compass arrow was never there and suggested it’s entirely new for these versions.

Does anyone have an official statement from Apple as to what’s happening? Is their constant tracking new, or is their disclosure of constant tracking new, and can it be configured to track only when I’m actually using Find My app to find a device?

Comment: Location Services itself constantly tracks. All you're seeing is when an app *asks* LS for the current location. For any 3rd party app I might be worried, bust as Find My is a core Apple service, I wouldn't let it bother me.

Comment: Did Apple change how often they track, or when they disclose their tracking?